# How to handle multiple ocaml types in ocaml?

Tags: types, compiler-construction, ocaml

I'm building a compiler in Ocaml and I got a problem.. I've one variable called value and this variable should receive any kind of ocaml type(int, float, char or bool), but I can't do it..

```
type info = {  
  initialized: bool;
  mutable value : int;
}
```

I tried creating a new type like this:

```
type tipos = int 
           | float
           | char
           | bool
```

and define info as:

```
type info = {  
  initialized: bool;
  mutable value : tipos;
}
```

but it still don't work..

Anyone can help me? thank you.

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: Kinda solved it following Jeffrey instructions, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need constructors for your different variants. Something like this will at least be a lot closer to working:

```
type tipos = Int of int | Float of float | Char of char | Bool of bool
```

Then values of the type look like this:

```
# Int (3 * 5);;
- : tipos = Int 15
# Float (3.2 /. 2.0);;
- : tipos = Float 1.6
# Char 'a';;
- : tipos = Char 'a'
# Bool true;;
- : tipos = Bool true
```